# How to recursively parse json value in ObjectMapper.readValue?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to parse json strings inside a json string into an Object using Jackson ObjectMapper. But I can't find a clean way to do this.

I have a SQL table storing Lists as json strings like `"[1,2,3]"`. And I read all columns out into a Map then tries to use `objectMapper.convertValue` to make into a Java Object.

So here's a quick snippet to recreate the problem. Do note I don't control how the Map is generated in the actual code.

```
@Data
public class Main {
    private List<Integer> bar;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> objectMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        objectMap.put("bar", "[1,2,3]");
        // Main foo = objectMapper.convertValue(objectMap, Main.class)
        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objectMap);
        Main foo = objectMapper.readValue(json, Main.class);

        System.out.println(foo.getBar());
    }
}
```

But this is not right. Instead of parsing the string, ObjectMapper tries to convert String to List directly and failed. I would expect foo.getBar() returns a List with 3 elements, but the code already failed at converting stage.

Comment: Try using ```"[{1},{2},{3}]"```. And make sure you have declared a field in ```Main``` that is ```@JsonProperty("bar") List<Integer>;```

Answer (score 0):

You should make `"[1,2,3]"` as `String[]` so:

```
"[1,2,3]".replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").replaceAll("\\s", "").split(",")
```

Something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> objectMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
        put("bar", "[1,2,3]".replaceAll("\\[", "")
                            .replaceAll("]", "")
                            .replaceAll("\\s", "").split(","));
    }};

    String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objectMap);
    Main foo = objectMapper.readValue(json, Main.class);

    System.out.println(foo.getBar());
}
```

you just need to replace the `"[1,2,3]"` with what ever you getting it from.

Note: Not sure about the application logic

Comment: The problem is that I can't edit the map. I'm looking for some kind of annotation that makes the objectmapper parses the String instead of tries to cast it directly.